# Ubuntu software center is not opening, it just freezes and then closes itself

Tags: software-center

When I try to remove software using the terminal I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/extras.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These terminal commands should solve your problem:

First remove the Merge List by opening a terminal and type this,

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

Next, generate a new one by running a simple update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```